# How to read 10 million rows from POSTGRES and write the data to a CSV in python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to run a query on a table which has about 10 million rows. Basically I am trying to run `Select * from events` and then I am writing it to a CSV file.

Here is the code:

```
    with create_server_connection() as connection:
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      cursor.itersize = 20000
      cwd = os.getcwd()
      query = open( sql_file_path, mode='r').read()
      print(query)
      cursor.execute(query)
      with open(file_name, 'w', newline='')as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp)
        for row in cursor:
          a.writerow(row)
```

```
def create_server_connection():
    DB_CONNECTION_PARAMS = os.environ["DB_REPLICA_CONNECTION"]
    json_object = json.loads(DB_CONNECTION_PARAMS)
    try:
      conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database=json_object["PGDATABASE"], user=json_object["PGUSER"], password=json_object["PGPASSWORD"], host=json_object["PGHOST"], port=json_object["PGPORT"]
      )  
    except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
      print('Unable to connect!\n{0}').format(e)
      sys.exit(1)

    return conn
```

However, for some reason, this whole process is taking up a lot of memory. I am running this as an AWS-batch process and the process exits with this error  `OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory usage`

Is there a way to reduce memory usage?

Comment: Did you try pandas read_sql?
You can read it in chunks and write it
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: Why not use `COPY` to export to CSV directly? There's no faster way than have the database itself export the data.

Comment: @TomRon pandas will be far worse. If the process fails when the data is cached once, it will fail far faster if the data has to be cached into a dataframe before exporting starts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what if I want to run a complex query rather than simply running Select * statements ?

Comment: COPY doesn't care about the query's complexity - provided it's actually a query instead of a multi-statement script. Client cursors cache the data on the client anyway - that's why they're called *client* cursors, because the data is on the client. You'll have to use a server-side cursor (just pass a name to `cursor`). The default batch size is I think 2K rows but can change with the `iterrows` attribute

Comment: Is this an RDS database or one hosted on an AWS VM? AWS has ways to quickly export data from RDS to S3.

Answer (score 1):

From the [psycopg2 docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors):

> When a database query is executed, the Psycopg cursor usually fetches all the records returned by the backend, transferring them to the client process. If the query returned an huge amount of data, a proportionally large amount of memory will be allocated by the client.

> If the dataset is too large to be practically handled on the client side, it is possible to create a server side cursor. Using this kind of cursor it is possible to transfer to the client only a controlled amount of data, so that a large dataset can be examined without keeping it entirely in memory.